# How can I join 3 tables, limit the query based on a condition, and return empty columns if condition not met?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following query currently:

```
select * from people
LEFT JOIN addresses
ON people.id = addresses.id
LEFT JOIN pers
ON people.id = pers.pers_id
WHERE people.id =:id
AND addresses.is_primary = 'Y'
```

Of course if there is no address where is_primary = 'Y' for a given person, the query doesn't return any results.

Without is_primary='Y', the query returns multiple addresses.

Is there any way, instead, to return null columns for all of the address fields in the event where there is no record for the id where is_primary = 'Y'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
select *
  from people
  LEFT JOIN addresses
    ON people.pidm = addresses.pidm
   and addresses.is_primary = 'Y'
 RIGHT JOIN pers
    ON people.id = pers.pers_id
 WHERE people.id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
 select *,case when addresses.is_primary not in('Y') then 'primary address different' else addresses.is_primary end as  is_primary  from people
    LEFT JOIN addresses
    ON people.pidm = addresses.pidm
    RIGHT JOIN pers
    ON people.id = pers.pers_id
    WHERE people.id =:id
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you not mix `left join` and `right join`.  The query is just so hard to follow.

Instead, start with the table where you want to keep all the rows.  Then only use `left join`.  Sometimes, you may need to put conditions in the `on` clause.

In your case:

```
select *
from people p left join
     addresses a
     on p.pidm = a.pidm and a.is_primary = 'Y' left join
     pers
     on p.id = pers.pers_id
where p.id = :id;
```